# search list in our application in android?

Tags: android, listview, search, textwatcher

Hi in my app there is a list view and a search section.what i need to do is when i search a word in the search section it should sort out the corresponding list view according to the word that i search.i got a code for sorting  the name , but my real problem is if i need to search a word for example i need to search

> Ramz super

which is a single name in my current code i need to search like from R then A etc in the correct order to sort out the name .But what i need is that if i start search from **Super** i need to show the name **Ramz super** in the listview.how can i do this my current search code is as shown below

```
    search_sort.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            textlength = search_sort.getText().length();
            array_sort.clear();
            contactnumber_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < contactname.size(); i++) {
                if (textlength <= contactname.get(i).length()) {
                    if (search_sort.getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) contactname.get(i).subSequence(
                                            0, textlength))) {
                        array_sort.add(contactname.get(i));
                        contactnumber_sort.add(contactnumber.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(array_sort);

            myadp = new myAdapter(MobiMailActivity.this, array_sort, contactnumber_sort);
            contactlist.setAdapter(myadp);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `contains()` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase()`.Where `datasetList` is object of my custom `ArrayList<ContactList>`.

```
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String getSearchString = search.getText().toString();

        if(datasetList != null && datasetList.size() > 0)
        {
            sortedList = new ArrayList<ContactDataSet>(); //new List sorted list 

            for (int i = 0; i < datasetList.size(); i++) {

                if (datasetList.get(i).getName().contains(getSearchString)) {
                    sortedList.add(datasetList.get(i));

                }
            }
        }           
        adapter.setnewList(sortedList);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Try this and let me know.It is working for me.Hope this helps you

Comment: when i use it not getting any values

Comment: @Ramz How come! check your sortedList() is having data or not because i am using this code and i am getting the result.can you post your updated source code?

Comment: ya sorry got the final answer thank you got it i use if (contactname.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) {
      array_sort.add(contactname.get(i));
      contactnumber_sort.add(contactnumber.get(i));
      contactemail_sort.add(contactemail.get(i));

     }                                by modify your code thank you :)