# how to show contact list names in an AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

I am trying to use the names from the phones contact list with AutoCompleteTextView so when the user starts typing a name it will show suggestions to auto complete from his contacts.
Plus it's done within a custom dialog.

But it doesn't work.

Here is the relevant code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView friendName;


        case R.id.add_debt_menu:

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_debt_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Add Debt");


            friendName = (AutoCompleteTextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
         name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        contacts.add(name);

    }
    cursor.close();


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,contacts);
    friendName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Solved! I used:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

So the key was using CommonDataKinds. I still have no idea though why it didn't work with the other method.

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/fdg3QmAq

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934283/autocomplete-textview-with-contacts

Comment: @Varundroid thanks , that example gave me a hint to use CommonDataKinds instead of ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME and it worked, instead of the email i used ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME

Comment: @BaradDedi why at all are you using `ArrayAdapter` ???

Comment: @pskink for the AutoCompleteTextView thats what they show in all the examples i saw except what you linked i guess, didnt see your method used anywhere, your saying its better? 
i didnt even try it since i cant even see how it connects to the AutoCompleteTextView since theres no findViewById

Comment: what `findViewById`? this code is a complete working code where you use no xml layout files and thats why there is no `findViewById`, jaust paste my code in `onCreate` and run it