# how to popup all contacts and give user option to select one of the contacts?

Tags: android

I writing some application and in some place on my code - i need to give the user an option to select on of the them.

Is there any option to popup the all contacts and get back the selected contact ?

( i don't need autocomplete contact - i need to show all the contact on popup window )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoComplete TextView with Contacts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934283/autocomplete-textview-with-contacts)

Comment: i don't need autocomplete contact - i need to show them all

Comment: Okay, then just take the Contacts ContentProvider code from that post