# Input and send to multiple contacts android app

Tags: android, sms, contacts

I have a module that sends message to a single contact. I want it to cover up to 5 contacts. Been searching but I haven't found anything useful to my app.

Here is layout of the send message:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/enterRecipient"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />   

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"       
        />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:text="@string/msg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />     
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:hint="@string/entermsg"
        android:gravity="top"         
        />          
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send"
        />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java code the responds to the send click:

```
public class PanicButton extends Activity {

Button btnSendSMS;
EditText txtPhoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_panicbutton);          

    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {                
            String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
            String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
            if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
                sendSMS(phoneNo, message);                
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please enter both phone number and message.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });        
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, PanicButton.class), 0);                
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
}
```

Any ideas? And I also want to have a choice if the user want to search numbers on his mobile contacts or input manually. Any ideas??

Comment: take all the numbers into a array and send arr[0],arr[1]....like send it

Comment: As @jenuine is correct and use `addTextChangeListener()` for searching number see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/11879375/704374

Comment: can you give me and example on how should I implement what you just just said? thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending sms to multiple contacts using loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276712/sending-sms-to-multiple-contacts-using-loop)